# Find all neighbors within point-specific radius in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am implementing Equation 8 from Kraskov et al (2004)'s [Estimating Mutual Information](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.69.066138) paper, and have the following problem:

Given vectors `X = [X_1,...,X_N]` and `r = [r_1,...,r_N]`, I need to compute `A= [A_1,...A_N]` where `A_i` is the number of points in `X` within a `r_i` radius of `X_i`.

If `r` were a fixed number, that is, if the radius around each point was fixed for all points, I could easily use [rangesearch](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/stats/rangesearch.html).  But because it is a vector (different radius for each point), I am not sure how to do this fast.  Exhaustive search (or making any `N^2` sized distance arrays) is not good, because `N` is on the order of a million.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you might want to first order points ascending by 'x' coordinate (or any other coordinate), and make sure the order of radiuses is consistent with the order of your points. From then on, you just need to do 2 checks per point. One to see if it reaches the previous points, and the other one to see if it reaches the next point. hope this helps. Not sure how well it performs in matlab, but order ascending should be no more than O(log n), and algorithm should run in O(n) as it's a constant number of operations per point

Comment: give us an example of inputs and outputs

Comment: 1) how many dimensions in X_i ?
2) euclidian norm used for distance metric ?
3) can you give a minimal working example for a few pts?